# Bodmas and square root evaluating curiosity

Tags: roots

When evaluating a problem where there is a square root, should I assume that the square root falls under the order part of bodmas?

Comment: $\sqrt{\cdots} = (\cdots)^{\frac12},$ so yes, and treat the inside of a square root as its own group.

Comment: Square roots and other functions typically come with brackets (in the case of square roots this can be shown by the *vinculum* - the horizontal line above).  Evaluate what is inside the brackets and then apply the function

Comment: For those like me that hadn't ever met acronym BODMAS : https://www.twinkl.fr/teaching-wiki/bodmas ...

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing [Order of operations (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations),

> The order of operations is
>
> 0. parentheses
> 1. exponentiation and **root extraction**
> 2. multiplication and division
> 3. addition and subtraction

The term **root extraction** refers to taking the $n$th root. In your case $n = 2$, so you can evaluate square roots as you would exponents.

**Example:**

\begin{align}
& \quad 5 \times 2^2 + \sqrt{16 + 9} \\
&= 5 \times 2^2 + \sqrt{(16 + 9)}\\
&=5 \times 2^2 + \sqrt{25}\\
&= 5 \times 2^2 + 5\\
&=5 \times 4 + 5\\
&=20 + 5\\
&=25
\end{align}